# Remove line that contain some certain character

Tags: php, html

I wanna remove line of txt file that contain `--` and `~`

here's the code :

```
function removeUnusedLines($string){
    if (strpos($string,'--') > 0 || strpos($string,'~') > 0 ) {
       $string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $string );
       return $string;
    }
}
$file  = "C:/AppServ/www/kbbi/try.txt";
$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line){
   $remove = removeUnusedLines($line);
   echo $remove.'<br>';
}
```

example :

```
Poetry is a form of literature ~ that uses aesthetic and rhythmic
qualities of language —- such as phonaesthetics, sound symbolism

metre to evoke meanings in addition to, or in place of, the prosaic ostensible meaning
```

From example, I wanna get just the last because the first and the second line consist `~` and `--`

but it doesnt remove the line. help me please, thank you :)

Comment: **`str_replace(array('--', '~'), '', $string);`** ?

Comment: @Darren I wanna remove the line, not the character

Comment: Could you show us what the text file could look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/.*(--|~).*[\r]?[\n]?/', '', $string);
```

So it looks for everyting on one line `.*`, followed by either `--` or `~`, followed again by everything on that line `.*`. Optionally followed by carriage return `\r` and/or new line `\n`.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/l8HZ3xso)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`preg_grep`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$lines = preg_grep('/--|~/', file($file), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Answer (score 0):

with your sintax you don't catch string who begin with -- and ~

according to [strpos documentation](http://www.php.net/strpos)

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>   Returns **FALSE** if the needle was not found.

```
function removeUnusedLines($string){
    if (strpos($string,'--') === FALSE && strpos($string,'~') === FALSE ) {
       $string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $string );
       return $string;
    }
}
```

You must revert condition :) if not found return the string.